# $6x^2-12x+3=p(x-2)$ where $p$ is a prime number. find values of $p$ such that the equation has at least one integer solution

Tags: functions, prime-numbers, integers

Hello I have a question: $6x^2-12x+3=p(x-2)$ where $p$ is a prime number. find values of $p$ such that the equation has at least one integer root.

What I did:

$${6x^2-12x+3}=p(x-2)$$
$$6x^2-(12+p)x+3+2p=0$$
then discriminant must be greater or eqault to $0$ for it to have a solution for $x$.
$$D\ge0$$
$$(12+p)^2-24(3+2p)\ge0$$
$$p^2-24p+72\ge0$$
$$p\in(-\infty;12-6\sqrt2)]\cup[12+6\sqrt2 ;\infty)$$
and because $p$ is prime it can be those values:
$$p\in\{3, 23, 29, 31, 37... \}$$
then I checked for $3,23,29,31$ and $37$ if the above equation has at least one integer root and for only $p=3$ and $p=31$ works so these are the answers but how to know that max is $31$ and after that there is no prime number that works, and I tried to check that, I ran a program that checked values for like $80000$ prime numbers but only $3$ and $31$ works.
I also thought that:
$$x=\frac{(12+p)\pm\sqrt{p^2-24p+72}}{12}$$ and for it to have an integer solution we need $p^2-24p+72$ to be perfect square of something but I don't know if it is worth checking.

Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: $(p,x)=(3,1)$ and $(31,5)$...

Comment: $p^2-24p+72=(p-12)^2-72=k^2$ so $72=(p-12-k)(p-12+k)$.  Check the factors of $72$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We must have $x-2$ divides the quadratic, and also the quadratic can be written as $6x(x-2)+3$ so we must have $x-2 \ |\  3$, and then it is just very easy case work... We only cared about integer roots so you should have a number theoretic approach, not work with discriminants...

Comment: The discriminant must be a perfect square, which is still number theoretic